# Can i migrate one table without affecting my data in the database?

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I'm asking if can do migration of one table without affecting my data in database, because everytime i refresh all my fields get reseted.

Comment: Are you asking if you could run a migration again after you've edited it?

Comment: How exactly do you run your migration? Usually a migration is not affecting data. That is more or less the reason to use migrations. Can you edit your post and put in the entire migration file and the terminal command you use to migrate?

Comment: If you want to edit your table, in example: add column, then you should write migration that only adds that column and run in normally, not by using migrate:fresh. It will add that column and keep other tables untouched.

Comment: i want to add a new table in my database i created the migration file, what i want is to execute to migrate only the file that i just created

Comment: @OthmaneMessaoud You could just run `php artisan migrate` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `php artisan migrate` it would run any migrations that haven't yet been run and it wouldn't remove your existing data unless you're deleting columns. You could also run a specific single migration by adding the path to the file with the `--path` parameter, e.g. `php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/2019_04_10_migration_name.php`.

Comment: it says nothing to migrate